# How can I kick all Discord members without a role?

Tags: python, discord, member

I've setup a custom bot in Discord with presence and members, added it the server with admin permissions. These are the codes I tried running, but with no avail:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kicknorole(ctx: commands.Context):
    members = ctx.guild.members
        
    for member in members:
        if len(member.roles) == 1:
            await member.kick()
            print(member.name)
    await ctx.reply('Done!')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

and

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kicknorole(ctx: commands.Context):
    members = ctx.guild.members
        
    for member in members:
        if len(member.roles) == 0:
            await member.kick()
            print(member.name)
    await ctx.reply('Done!')

bot.run('token')
```

These codes run, but no error shows up and the number of members doesn't go down.

This was my final try:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
from discord import Intents
intents = Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
@bot.command()
async def noroleskick(ctx):
    # iterate through guild members and kick members with only 1 (@everyone) role
    # increase kicked counter +1 for each kicked member
    guild_members = ctx.guild.members
    kicked = 0
    for member in guild_members:
        if len(member.roles) == 1:
            await member.kick()   
            kicked += 1 
 
     
bot.run('tokengoeshere')
```

I'd greatly appreciate help!

Comment: According to official discord documentation, `GUILD_MEMBERS` is a [Privileged Intent](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#privileged-intents). That means that unless you go through their verification process (which AFAIK is pretty privacy intrusive) your bot won't be able to get a list of a server's members

Comment: That's discord.py right? I'm not familiar with it but check if it supports the prune functionality. By default, pruning will only remove members that have no additional roles (and according to the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#begin-guild-prune) you can manually specify the days of inactivity. Also, considering that message content will soon become a privileged intent, your bot will not work in the near future unless you implement slash commands. Just a heads up!

Comment: @guard3 - I have enabled  PRESENCE, SERVER MEMBERS and MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT.  

Since I'm running this bot on a single server, I shouldn't be affected by the issue: 
"Unverified bots and apps will not be impacted by this change and can continue to use message content in their bot development without requesting any Privileged Intent."